# CSRF Token mismtach error in laravel ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi guys i am trying to insert form values in db using jquery ajax..while inserting i am getting error as CSRF Token mismatch.
Tried inserting csrf token from headers.but still it is showing same error.

Here is my code:

```
function saveFile()
        {
            chk_EnumValuesValidation = chkEnumValuesValidation(isSoltion, stepCount);
            if(!chk_EnumValuesValidation)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Function to push "MainArray" in current Solution
                pushVarMainArrayInThisSolution(isSoltion, var_main_arr.var_arr_values);
                // alert('Aalaaaaaaa');
                arr                = ar;
                var subject_list   = $('#qtype_subject_id').val();
                var ddl_topic_type = $('#qtype_topic_id').val();
                var qtype_name = $('#qtype_name').val();
                var qtype_option = $('#qtype_option').val();
                var batch = [];
                $(".batch:checked").each(function ()
                {
                    batch.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
                });

                var sendInfo       = {
                    'arr':arr,
                    'saveFile':1,
                    'subject_list':subject_list,
                     'topic_list':ddl_topic_type,
                      'qtype_name':qtype_name,
                      'qtype_option': qtype_option
                  };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/eqtype-editor/store",
                    type: "POST",
                    data :sendInfo,

                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        data = JSON.parse(response);
                        if(data.Success == 'Success')
                        {
                            // for same file creation when again click on save button
                            alert('Your file is saved!');
                            // window.location.href="qtype_list.php?pag=Masters";
                        }
                        else
                        {

                         alert(data.resp);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error)
                    {},
                    complete: function()
                    {}
                });
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help me where i did mistake.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Add this in Your HTML Header Section**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

**Your Ajax POST Function should be**

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/eqtype-editor/store",
     type: "POST",
     data :sendInfo,
     headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     success: function(response){
       handle Success here.....
     }
   });
```